# MMA11.3 - PlotLegends - bug?

Tags: plotting, bugs, legending

```
    ParametricPlot[  {Table[{Cos[t] - Cos[n*t], Sin[t] - Sin[n*t]}, {n, 6, 10, 1}]}  , {t, 0, 8*Pi}, GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True,  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

What can't I see the `PlotLegends`.

[image]

Only if I separately execute it, then I can see them.
Is there an easier way to do this?
[image]

Comment: Please post CODE (not pictures of code).  FOR *ALL* your code... including the code that generated the figures.

Comment: Also note that you do not need to put `Table` in a list as it generates a list.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `Evaluate` the `Table` so it "knows" what the expressions are:

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[{Cos[t] - Cos[n t], Sin[t] - Sin[n t]},
   {n, 6, 10}],
 {t, 0, 8 \[Pi]},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

Also, you added unnecessary brackets around your `Table`.